# Base64 encoding Email _ Displaying as text not html

Tags: php, email, base64

Hi this is my first time trying to use base64 encoding.

Everything seems to be fine with what I am trying to do, except when I send an email, it gives me all the tags (plain text) in the email and it doesn't display the HTML correctly.

Here is an example of how the email comes through:

```
html>body>center>table  bgcolor="#012b2b" width="100%">tr>td align="center">img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/sABFEdWNreQABAAQAAABGAAD...
```

I removed all the < firts brackets for this post.

What I have done so far is this:

```
$pathr = "http://www.aboutitgroup.com/dev/sbtours/files/6113/7059/1223/NewsLetter.jpg"

$sep = sha1(date('r', time()));

$attachment = file_get_contents($pathr);

$encoded = base64_encode($attachment);

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

$headers .= " Content-Type: text/html;
            boundary=\"PHP-mixed-{$sep}\"";

$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64";

$subject = 'Newsletter';

$messages ="... img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.$encoded.'"/>...';
```

Could someone please explain why the message does not display in HTML but only plain text.

When I copy the email text that comes through, and save it as an HTML file it displays correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you running this on a Linux or Windows based host? You may want to check your line breaks to ensure they're not causing issues with your headers. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems relevant: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?185299-Sending-a-HTML-email-in-base64-HELP

In particular:

> To tell if the router is the problem try "quoted/printable" encoding type ...or maybe even 7bit ...it's not optimum but it should give you different results.
>
> to test the server and client apps, make sure to specify the mime version and charset intended, its not always implied...also, since you are not doing the message in multipart and trying to display the message in line, I wouldn't even chunck-split it. Try:

```
$to = "kit@huntingsportsplus.net"; 
$subject = "$lastName, $firstName - $propertyCounties, $propertyStates - $totalAcreage Acres - $emailAddress"; 
mail ($to,$subject,$message,"From: info@hunt-private-land.com <info@hunt-private-land.com>\n"."MIME-Version: 1.0\n"."Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
```

Personally I'd use the Zend_Mail object - it saves you from having to do the hard work. Here's a good starting point: http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/how-to-show-images-inside-a-html-Zend-Mail-td645323.html

Finally if you need to know how your message will render in different mail clients you can use Litmus to check this:

Comment: Thank you, This seems to work. Message on www.webdeveloper....  adds rtrim().  that seemed to do the trick